# getAttribute on IE9

Tags: javascript

This works on all browser except IE9, getAttribute return null on IE9, any ideas

```
function getFlashMovieObject(movieName){
    if(document.embeds[movieName])
      return document.embeds[movieName];
    if(window.document[movieName])
      return window.document[movieName];
    if(window[movieName])
      return window[movieName];
    if(document[movieName])
      return document[movieName];
}

function ChangePlaylist(newval,mymovievarmp3){
    var mp3Player = getFlashMovieObject(mymovievarmp3);
    var newstring = mp3Player.getAttribute('data');
    var broken = new Array();
    broken = newstring.split('?');
    mp3Player.setAttribute('data',broken[0]+'?'+broken[1]+'?'+newval)
}
```

Using JQuery but still does not work

```
    var mp3Player = getFlashMovieObject(mymovievarmp3);
    var newstring = $("#mp3Player ").data("data");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
 function ChangePlaylist(newval,mymovievarmp3){
     var mp3Player = getFlashMovieObject(mymovievarmp3);
     //previus declaration
     //var newstring = mp3Player.attributes['data'].nodeValue;

     //Although i'm not familiar with getFlashMoiveObject, if that function
     //a reference to the javascript object, the next should work fine. 
     var newstring = $(mp3Player).attr('data');

     //If that does not work, then try adding an `id`, or a `class` to the object
     //and then do one of the next:

     //using `id`:
     //var newstring = $('#mp3PlayerId').attr('data');


     //using `class`:
     //var newstring = $('.mp3PlayerClass').attr('data');

     //Also note that `id` and `class` are standard attributes, and so they values can
     //be accessed using regular getAttribute.

     var broken = new Array();
     broken = newstring.split('?');
     //mp3Player.setAttribute('data',broken[0]+'?'+broken[1]+'?'+newval)

     //Update - To set the a value to data attribute:
     $(mp3Player).attr('data',broken[0]+'?'+broken[1]+'?'+newval);
 }
```

IE have issues getting non standard attributes from elements.

**Update**:

If you are willing to use another library such as `jQuery` you can easily do something like

```
  $('#elementId').attr('data');
```

And is going to be crossbrowser for sure.

**Update 2**

I updated the code and explained a bit. Hope it helps you out!

**Update 3**

The following code can be used to set value to data:

```
     $(mp3Player).attr('data',value);
```

Comment: not good with jquery, can you please rewrite the above function for me using jquery, thanks

Comment: Now I can get the data identifier but IE still won't set the attr, it looks like no solution for this since SWFObject 2.0 has no way to setup id or class inside it even if we get the attribute out, setting it up will have the same challenge since it is not standard either.

Comment: Hm, that is very weird i use jquery to obtain not standard attributes in my applications. One question though, you are trying to set or to get? either way it can be achived with jQuery, im going to update for set.

Comment: I just gave up on IE9, let it be.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function ChangePlaylist(newval,mymovievarmp3){
    var mp3Player = getFlashMovieObject(mymovievarmp3);
    var newstring = mp3Player.getAttribute('data');
    var broken = new Array();
    broken = newstring.split('?');
    mp3Player.setAttribute('data',broken[0]+'?'+broken[1]+'?'+newval)
}
```

I now understand why you escaped things. I think it breaks on the getAttribute() line.
I suggest importing jQuery and use $(elem).data().

Say you have:

```
<a data-someval="blah" />
```

Then this:

```
$("#elem").data("someval");
```

Should return blah.

Comment: escaping or not, it does not make a different for IE9, it works on all others.

Comment: @user1473174 _it works on all others_ I doubt that... That's a syntax error par excellance

Comment: now it is standalone and still does not work on IE9, on all others is fine.

Comment: what? It's in PHP? That explains things a bit. I would advise you to go to your own side and post the javascript received by the browser. Escaping makes things unreadable and hard to debug. @user1473174

Comment: it is now standalone script and still works on all browsers except IE9. Using alert all browsers get the attribute except IE "undefin"

Comment: JQuery is imported how do I use $(elem).data()

Comment: $(elem).data() caused all browsers not to wark.

Comment: you sure you did it just like me? Can you show me what have tried? @user1473174